# Why IBOutlets inside document based aplication IBActions are nil?

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder, osx-lion, automatic-ref-counting

If I do the following:
- Create a document based application project;
- Create a class which inherits from NSView which I'll call CustomView;
- Drag into document.xib a view and set it's class to CustomView;
- Connect the view with the document, with an outlet which I'll call customView;
- Add an IBAction to the document, which I'll call Foo;
- Connect this IBAction in the mainmenu.xib file to a menu item;

Then inside the IBAction all outlets are nil:

```
- (IBAction) Foo: (id) sender
{
    NSLog(@"%p",customView);
}
```

It prints 0x0.
The problem occurs with all IBOutlets, and only if the IBAction is linked with a menu item.If Instead I try to print instance variables, they have the correct value.

Comment: What is the File's Owner of the XIB?  Implement `awakeFromNib` in that class and log there to see if that is called *before* your actions are invoked (also, it's good practice to `assert()` that all outlets are not `nil` at this point).  Sometimes you have to do something explicit to ensure a XIB is loaded, e.g. for an `NSWindowController` you need to request the `window` to trigger loading.

Comment: Yes, in all other methods the outlets are not nil.Even if I trigger the pressure of a button with a method that prints all outlets, they're printed correctly.Only if I connect a method to a menu item I get all nil outlets when the method get called.Is that clear? I could post the link of a video otherwise ...

Comment: "Connect this `IBAction` in the `mainmenu.xib` file to a menu item;" How did you expose the `IBAction` in `mainmenu.xib` (get it to show up)? `NSDocument` subclasses doesn't show up in `mainmenu.xib` by default.

Comment: I dragged an object and set it's class name to Document, then ctrl-dragged the name of the action to the menu item.

Comment: No, that won't work. You're basically creating a brand new instance of Document that has nothing to do with the other Document in Document.xib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't create a new `Document` object in `MainMenu.xib`, because all that does is create a brand new `Document` object that is in no way related to the actual `Document`s that you're opening (hence, the nil value of `customView`).

To get the active `Document` object with the `customView`, instead, connect the menu item with your specified `IBAction` to the `First Responder` - AppKit automatically passes up the action message up the chain to the active `Document` subclass if none of the other responders handle it. Maybe read up on "Action Messages" in the Event Handling Documentation: ([reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH3-SW7)).

Comment: This is also applicable when using a non-document-based application. I had an NSWindowController instance inside my MainMenu.xib in IB, but I was creating the controller in code. Deleting the instance in IB and reconnecting the outlets to first responder fixed it. Thanks!